# Addins interop-access 15-20x faster than in a windows application

Tags: c#, performance, office-interop, word-addins

I don't know, if StackOverflow is the right place to ask about Performance issues, but I haven't found any better community for this issue yet.

Basically we have two sample programs, one is an addin and one is a winforms program referencing the Word interop.

Both have implemented the same method called `GetTabsFromParagraph`:

```
public class SlowExample
{
    public static void GetTabsFromParagraph(Paragraph para, Style style, List<Tabulator> tabList, bool getTabsForCase = false)
    {
        foreach (TabStop tab in para.TabStops)
        {
            if (tab.CustomTab)
            {
                bool showTab = true;
                foreach (TabStop ts in style.ParagraphFormat.TabStops)
                {
                    if (Math.Abs(ts.Position - tab.Position) < 0.001 &&
                        ts.Alignment == tab.Alignment)
                    {
                        showTab = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (showTab || getTabsForCase)
                {
                    Tabulator t = new Tabulator
                    {
                        Tabulatorausrichtung = 
                            tab.Alignment == WdTabAlignment.wdAlignTabLeft
                                ? TabulatorAusrichtung.Links 
                                : TabulatorAusrichtung.Rechts,
                        Tabulatorart = TabulatorArt.Tabulator,
                        Position = tab.Position
                    };

                    tabList.Add(t);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!getTabsForCase)
        {
            foreach (TabStop ts in style.ParagraphFormat.TabStops)
            {
                if (ts.CustomTab)
                {
                    bool showTab = true;
                    foreach (TabStop tab in para.TabStops)
                    {
                        if (Math.Abs(tab.Position - ts.Position) > 0.0001 || tab.Alignment != ts.Alignment)
                        {
                            showTab = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (showTab)
                    {
                        Tabulator t = new Tabulator
                        {
                            Tabulatorausrichtung = TabulatorAusrichtung.Geloescht,
                            Tabulatorart = TabulatorArt.Tabulator,
                            Position = ts.Position
                        };
                        tabList.Add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (Math.Abs(para.LeftIndent - style.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent) > 0.001 || getTabsForCase)
        {
            Tabulator t = new Tabulator
            {
                Tabulatorausrichtung = TabulatorAusrichtung.Links,
                Tabulatorart = TabulatorArt.Einzug,
                Position = para.LeftIndent
            };
            tabList.Add(t);
        }
        if (Math.Abs(para.RightIndent - style.ParagraphFormat.RightIndent) > 0.001 || getTabsForCase)
        {
            Tabulator t = new Tabulator
            {
                Tabulatorausrichtung = TabulatorAusrichtung.Rechts,
                Tabulatorart = TabulatorArt.Einzug,
                Position = para.RightIndent
            };
            tabList.Add(t);
        }
        if (Math.Abs(para.FirstLineIndent - style.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent) > 0.001 || getTabsForCase)
        {
            Tabulator t = new Tabulator
            {
                Tabulatorausrichtung = TabulatorAusrichtung.ErstzeilenEinzug,
                Tabulatorart = TabulatorArt.Einzug,
                Position = para.FirstLineIndent
            };
            tabList.Add(t);
        }
    }

    public class Tabulator
    {
        private TabulatorArt m_Tabulatorart;
        private TabulatorAusrichtung m_Tabulatorausrichtung;
        private float m_Position;
        private bool m_UebernahmeInFolgedokument = false;

        public float Position
        {
            get { return m_Position; }
            set { m_Position = value; }
        }

        public float PositionOrg
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public float PositionInCm
        {
            get
            {
                return (m_Position / 28.35F);
            }
            set
            {
                m_Position = value * 28.35F;
            }
        }

        public TabulatorArt Tabulatorart
        {
            get { return m_Tabulatorart; }
            set { m_Tabulatorart = value; }
        }

        public TabulatorAusrichtung Tabulatorausrichtung
        {
            get { return m_Tabulatorausrichtung; }
            set { m_Tabulatorausrichtung = value; }
        }

        public TabulatorAusrichtung TabulatorausrichtungOrg
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public bool UebernahmeInFolgedokument
        {
            get { return m_UebernahmeInFolgedokument; }
            set { m_UebernahmeInFolgedokument = value; }
        }
    }

    public enum TabulatorArt
    {
        Invalid = 0,
        Tabulator = 1,
        Einzug = 2
    }

    public enum TabulatorAusrichtung
    {
        Invalid = 0,
        Links = 1,
        Rechts = 2,
        ErstzeilenEinzug = 3,
        Geloescht = 4,
    }
}
```

In each of the both programs, I load up a Application, open up a document with a few paragraphs and tabs and run this method for each paragraph like this:

```
    private void TestSlowMethod(Word.Document document)
    {
        Word.Paragraphs documentParagraphs = document.Paragraphs;
        List<Tabulator> tabList = new List<Tabulator>();
        long swElapsedMilliseconds = 0;
        foreach (Word.Paragraph documentParagraph in documentParagraphs)
        {
            Word.Style style = documentParagraph.get_Style();

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            SlowExample.GetTabsFromParagraph(documentParagraph, style, tabList, true);

            sw.Stop();
            swElapsedMilliseconds += sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "\r\n");
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Total ms: " + swElapsedMilliseconds);
        Debug.WriteLine("Done...");
    }
```

What I found out is the addin is running throw all of this 10-20 times faster.

- Addin: 20-30 ms per call
- WinForms tool: 200-300 ms per call

Why is that? My assumption would be, that the addin runs in the same context / process than the word application. But is that the real reason?

And can we fix that? Our software moved from addin to WPF + Interop-Word.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of add-in (using what technology)?

Comment: The addin is using the VSTO template. (Word 2013 and 2016 VSTO Add-in)

Comment: Any difference in how you've set the References to the PIAs? Do both use the same setting for Embed interop types property for each PIA? But, yes, because VSTO is loaded by the Word process it's going to be a bit faster, although never as fast as VBA (which runs in-process). If performance is critical you might do better to get the content as WordOpenXML and "parse" that since that would all run outside of the Word process, at .NET Framework speeds.

Comment: Is there a way to make some of the code run in the VSTO addin? I tried it by overriding the protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService() method. The call is executed successfully, but unfortunately it's still slow... Is it because I have to switch the threads or why is it still slow? I tried using the class "SynchronizationContext", which I set in ThisAddIn_Startup, but the method is still slow, even Inside of the Context.Send(o => { // Here's the slow code }, null)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know about what you're trying to do and the effect it has on speed. But fastest, without a doubt, would be to analyse the `Document.Content.WordOpenXML` rather than looping through Word objects.

Comment: I understand the part about the WordOpenXML. But I have a not-so-beautiful second solution: Create an addin, that exposes a method, which is called by my winforms app. In other way, my WinForms app communicates with the addin. That way I can do the "heavy" stuff now. The only thing I needed to do now is using the Dispatcher to run the "heavy" stuff on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Some performance fixes:

Check `getTabsForCase` sooner here:

```
    if (tab.CustomTab)
    {
        bool showTab = true;

        if (getTabsForCase) //insert this here, no need to run if getTabsForCase.
            foreach (TabStop ts in style.ParagraphFormat.TabStops)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(ts.Position - tab.Position) < 0.001 &&
                    ts.Alignment == tab.Alignment)
                {
                    showTab = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        if (showTab || getTabsForCase)
        {
            Tabulator t = new Tabulator
            {
                Tabulatorausrichtung = 
                    tab.Alignment == WdTabAlignment.wdAlignTabLeft
                        ? TabulatorAusrichtung.Links 
                        : TabulatorAusrichtung.Rechts,
                Tabulatorart = TabulatorArt.Tabulator,
                Position = tab.Position
            };

            tabList.Add(t);
        }
    }
```

Similarly, put the check on `getTabsForCase` before all calculations in `if` statements:

```
//see getTabsForCase goes first
if (getTabsForCase || Math.Abs(para.LeftIndent - style.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent) > 0.001)
```

Fix all of those conditionals to have `getTabsForCase` first - then the rest of the statement won't need to evaluate.

Comment: In our special case, the flag is always true (see the call). It's true, that you should do your fixes for sure, but unfortunately the fix won't do anything in this special case :)